# Need polygon intersect counts with buffered polygon neighbors FOR EACH polygon

Tags: sql, postgis

I'm trying to find whether its possible in purely SQL to generate a table with the number of intersects each polygon in a layer has with its corresponding neighboring polygons(buffered) in a buffered version of the layer.

A rough and flawed version is the following:

```
For each value in list:

SELECT 
    Count(*) 
INTO 
    intersectcounts
FROM
    parcels,parcelsbuffered
WHERE
    parcels.apn = value AND ST_INTERSECT(parcels.geom,parcelsbuffered.geom)
```

Here the geom is the polygon
I need as result like

intersectscount table

```
APN COUNT
100   3
101  87
...
...
```

I could use python loop and modify the query string with a different value in the WHERE clause but I dont think this will have good performance - there are thousands of parcels(polygons)

Comment: Why use a buffer? Try using [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) instead, which is much faster and more accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT parcels.apn, count(*) as intersectcounts
 FROM parcels 
 JOIN parcelsbuffered
   ON ST_INTERSECT(parcels.geom, parcelsbuffered.geom)
 GROUP BY parcels.apn
```

You probably want include some validation to remove the parcel intersect with his own buffered version like

```
(count(*) - 1) as intersectcounts
```

or

```
WHERE parcerls.apn <> parcelsbuffered.apn
```